# What is the name of this single slot PCB-mounted connector?

Tags: connector, identification

It's about 14mm wide and has 21 pins.

[image: photo of connector on PCB]

Comment: The pitch (distance between center of of pin) is more important than the size of the connector itself.

Comment: It looks like it's 1mm between pins on the same row.

Comment: Given you probably want to replace this, check the other side for damage as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a mezzanine connector. It interconnects directly two PCBs together. They are meant to provide "a mechanically secure, high density electrical interface between
 parallel printed circuit boards."

This specific connector is the 91930-21121LF, of the Conan/MezzSelect Series by Amphenol.

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/amphenol-icc-fci/91930-21121LF/609-1591-ND/1001905

Answer (score 8):

[image]

> 21 Position Connector Receptacle, Outer Shroud Contacts

https://www.digikey.ie/product-detail/en/amphenol-icc-fci/91930-21121LF/609-1591-ND/1001905

From Jasen's comment and datasheet:

> datasheet note 7 "the three slots may be located at either end"

Comment: yeah, something the mirrior image of that

Comment: datasheet note 7 "the three slots may be located at either end" so yeah that or a different height versiopn of that. https://cdn.amphenol-icc.com/media/wysiwyg/files/drawing/91900.pdf

Comment: Wonder why exactly those three slots are at either end... Probably a by product of the molding?

Comment: As a suggestion, How i search?.. I googled - 21pin, surface mount PCB connector -and scrolled through images

Comment: Thank you for help.

Answer (score -3):

the name of that connector should be 
"DIP pin connector" with 21p. check the length between the pin if the length between the pin (pitch) 1.27mm so your DIP connector is DIP female 1.27mm pitch 21p
you can check either online or in Mouser.com

or i could be wrong  but that's not like dip connector at all.. you could check the cable  (male version) for making sure, it's usually have code either in female or male housing.